# Linking private EOS node with EOS mainnet

Tags: nodeos, eosio.token

I want to build a scenario where I can exchange EOS private net tokens with EOS main net tokens.
Is there a way to directly link a private network with the main net, or do we have to involve some server that will do it for us???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want same tokens as it's in your private node then you need to deploy contract on mainnet But if you want your private net data on mainnet then there is no way to connect private network to main network. Yes, you can make your node in mainnet but it's a different thing than what you have asked. For more clarification please give more description.